# VSCode - Rider's alt + enter equivalent?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking for a shortcut which will try to automatically import unresolved class names (by automatically I mean it will take first item from list which appears when I hover over it and press "Quick fix")

I believe Rider does that upon pressing alt + enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default "Quick Fix" shortcut in vscode is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

You can also update it to whatever you like.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_code-actions-quick-fixes-and-refactorings

Answer (score 1):

This explains how to **change** the key binding in VS.Code to match IntelliJ

#### Change Alt+Enter only

Note that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> has following existing key bindings:

[image: Key bindings for Alt+Enter]

(You can reach that menu via File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts)

When you search for "quick fix", you see following entries:

[image: Entries for quick fix]

Change the first one to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: Quick fix changed to Alt+Enter]

Then, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> also works in VS Code.

#### Change all key bindings

The plugin [vscode-intellij-idea-keybindings](https://github.com/kasecato/vscode-intellij-idea-keybindings) changes all key bindings in VS.Code to the ones of IntelliJ.